# ASP.NET MVC3 Dependency Injection misunderstanding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    object resolvedObject = null;
    try
    {
        resolvedObject = _unityContainer.Resolve(serviceType);
    }
    catch(ResolutionFailedException e) { }

    return resolvedObject;
}
```

Is this best practice to catch exception and return null? By default mvc try to resolve IControllerFactory and IViewPageActivator, i.e. i get two catched exceptions. I don't prefer this solution.

My friend suggest to check serviceType on `IControllerFactory`, `IViewPageActivator` and if an exception is raised - catch and logged error. but as for me - it is not best solution, it like kind of hardcode.

Comment: This looks like you're using a service locator to resolve a dependency from an IoC container at run time.  Just so you know, that's a really, really bad idea, in so many ways.

Comment: I should use DefaultControllerFactory like in mvc 2? Could you explain why it is realy bad idea, please.

Comment: The title says it all...

Comment: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Answer (score 5):

MVC3's `DependencyResolver` is a service locator, first and foremost. It is essentially the lovechild of MVC and the Common Service Locator ([commonservicelocator.codeplex.com](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com)). The differences between a CSL service locator and MVC3's `DependencyResolver` is that the MVC architects decided that they needed a safer way of handling cases where services cannot be resolved through it, and the answer they chose was that the implementation of `IDependencyResolver` should return null in these circumstances.

With CSL implementations of IServiceLocator, the standard practice is to throw an `ActivationException` which allows for a standardised exception for handling these cases.

With MVC, the framework will call the `DependencyResolver` to try and resolve a configured service. If it cannot find a suitable service, it uses a default.

E.g., when it wants to find an `IControllerFactory`, it will check the `DependencyResolver` first. If it fails there, it will use the `DefaultControllerFactory` configured through `ControllerBuilder.SetControllerFactory(...)`. Because of this check-first approach, it's better to return null then let a container specific exception bubble up.

This means that you must catch/swallow any exception at this point, as it is not MVC framework's responsibility to handle it for you (the onus should be on the container/`IDependencyResolver` itself).

You could log this at this stage, but the practice with MVC3 is to return null in these instances.

Answer (score 0):

This obviously not a best practice, But ASP.NET MVC is implemented in way that when the IoC is not able to resolve a service it should return null, so that the mvc framework can fallback to its default. Pls note there are number of services other than controller/view factory depends on it, so throwing exception will break those from functioning.

I argued with the design decision in the internal asp.net mailing list, but this how it currently stands :-(.

Answer (score 0):

For IControllerFactory you can

```
.RegisterType<IControllerFactory, DefaultControllerFactory>()
```

I am not sure which classes implement IViewPageActivator and ModelMetadataProvider. Event though an exception can be swallowed, supressing exceptions it is not a good practice simply because in general exceptions affect performance. Once an exception is caought the framework populates stack trace which take time.